# Most efficient way to "consolidate overlap" of start and end times

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have a data structure:

```
class Segment{
    float startTime;
    float endTime;
}
```

And we have a bunch of segments, some of them with overlapping durations. What is the best way to consolidate these Segments to have nonoverlapping durations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create an array of all the start and end times, then to sort it into chronological order. You can then iterate over the array from left to right, at each point keeping track of the number of open intervals. Whenever you see a start time, you increment the number of intervals, and whenever you see an end time, you decrement the number of intervals. As you do this, any time you go from zero open intervals to one, record the start of a new interval, and whenever you go from one open interval to zero, record a close time.

Overall, this runs in time O(sort + n). If you use something like heap sort or quick sort, this is time O(n log n). If you use something like radix sort - assuming it's applicable - this would be time O(n log U), where U is the maximum value.

Hope this helps!